# Using self.object in CreateView to create objects in other tables

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

When a user makes a new listing using a `CreateView`, I am trying to use this new object to create a `Bid` in the `Bids` table.

```py
class ListingCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Listing 
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'starting_bid', 'url'] 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def post(self, request, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        starting_bid = self.request.POST['starting_bid']
        Bids.objects.create(bid_value=starting_bid, bidder=self.request.user, item=self.object)
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But it returns the error `Generic detail view ListingCreateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.object) say that "When using CreateView you have access to self.object, which is the object being created. If the object hasn’t been created yet, the value will be None."

When using a CreateView, when would `self.object` contain the object being created? How would I work with the object that has just been created in a `CreateView`?

Comment: Not when you override the `post` method, since then you basically destroy the functionality implemented by the `CreateView`...

Comment: Aah! I didn't know that would override the whole `post` method. Is there a more appropriate method I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the logic in the [**`.form_valid(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid), for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class ListingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Listing 
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'starting_bid', 'url'] 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()
        Bids.objects.create(
            bid_value=form.cleaned_data['starting_bid'],
            bidder=self.request.user,
            item=self.object
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Bid` instead of <s>`Bids`</s>.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Answer (score 0):

For such behaviour i **strongly** recommend using signals.py.

Your apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'your_app'

    def ready(self):
        import your_app.signals
```

signals.py (same folder)

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Bids, Listing 


@receiver(post_save, sender=Listing)
def create_bids(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Bids.objects.create(bidder=instance.author, ...)
```

`created` is variable added from Django - True if object has just been created, otherwise False. `instance` is the object you have just created. Signals are very powerful and you can use them pre- and post save but be aware, that not everything is possible here.

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/)

Comment: Thank you this looks interesting and I am glad you have made me aware of it! The solution I chose was easier to implement.

Comment: Sure thing, it's good solution but view-dependent. Just have in mind, that with signals you can have multiple views that will always acknowledge signals without copying code from one view to another :)